# CSS - Can't have a fixed navBar

Tags: css, ionic2

I am developing an app with IONIC2 framework, now I need to create a fixed navbar that sticks to the top of the screen; however, I was not lucky enough to make work.

So far, it works perfectly in chrome; however, when I run it on the device (Safari) the whole view becomes scrollable.

My implementation so far:

HTML:

```
        <ion-content id="contentPadding" class="outlet">
        <div class="top">
        <div class="imagebk" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url('+outlet.mainPhoto?.url+')'}"><div class="bk"></div></div>
        <div class="fixedTitle">
          <div class="outletName">{{outlet.resName | uppercase}}</div>
        </div>
        <ion-row id="rowPadding">
          <ion-col id="overviewTab" width-50>
          <div>TAB 1</div>
          </ion-col>

          <ion-col id="menuTab" (click)="showModal(outlet)" width-50>
          <div>TAB 2</div>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        </div>
       .....
     <div class="secondDiv"></div>
     </ion-content>
```

CSS:

```
   .top{
    position: fixed !important;
    top:0;
     }

    .fixedTitle{
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 13%;
      left: 50%;
      z-index: 101;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
     }

     #rowPadding{
    padding:50% 0 0vh 0;
    position: fixed;
   transform: translateX(0px);
   z-index: 5;
    }
```

With the above implementation when I scroll up/down on the device (iOS) the whole page goes up and down, and the navBar is not sticked to the top.

Comment: I don't think you need to have a position property set for any children of .top because they inherit it's styles.

Comment: That's true, but the thing is that I've done many trials, and the above one is the latest version..

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try with an `ion-toolbar`? According to [Ionic2 docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/toolbar/Toolbar/):

> A Toolbar is a generic bar that is positioned above or below content.
>   Unlike a `Navbar`, a toolbar can be used as a subheader. **When toolbars
>   are placed within an `<ion-header>` or `<ion-footer>`, the toolbars stay
>   fixed in their respective location**.

Also notice that

> When placed within `<ion-content>`, toolbars will scroll with the
>   content.

So instead of trying to put that code inside the `ion-content`, you should try by putting it inside a `ion-toolbar`, but including that `ion-toolbar` inside the `ion-header` and **not** in the `ion-content`.

Comment: Thanks for you point, using `ion-toolbar` it's not convenient for me as the new header I am designing is totally custom, it contains a background image, custom height...., so I need to know how IONIC fixed its navbar using CSS only